# For the smallest number of moves, we need to maximize the number of times we double the money

Tags: java

If you start with $1 and, with each move, you can either double your money or add another $1, what is the smallest number of moves you have to make to get to exactly n $

I wrote some code, but it looks that it stop before the end. I think I need another loop for else, but cannot find the solution. Anybody can help to adjust my code? I don't want complicated code if possible.

```
public class NumberOfMoves {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n$ = 200; //target number of bucks

        int steps = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < n$; i++) {
            if (n$ % 2 == 0) {    //if 200/2 equals even number than n$/2== this number
                n$ = n$ / 2;
                steps++;
                // System.out.println(n$);

            } else {
                n$ = n$ - 1;
                steps++;



            } // end else


        }// end loop
        System.out.println("Steps " + steps);


    } //end main


} //end class
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `i` and a for loop that way. Why not do `while (n > 1)`? Isn't `n = 1` what you start with?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about when you should exit the `for` loop. You're decreasing `n$`, and it looks like you should stop as soon as `n$` is 1. So what is `i` doing? It's counting up and will reach `n$` at some point before `n$` reaches 1. I think the loop should just be `while (n$ > 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
package sample;

class Main1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n$ = 200; //target number of bucks

        int steps = 0;


        while (n$>1) {
            if (n$ % 2 == 0) {    //if 200/2 equals even number than n$/2== this number
                n$ = n$ / 2;
                steps++;
                // System.out.println(n$);

            } else {
                n$ = n$ - 1;
                steps++;



            } // end else


        }// end loop
        System.out.println("Steps " + steps);


    } //end main


} //end class}
```

you can use while instead of for

Comment: I think you mean `while (n$>1)`? The OP said they started out with $1

Comment: if (n$>1) then it will stop at 2 so count will be reduced by 1  its (n$>0)

Comment: No, it'll keep going until it's 1, and then the condition will be false, so it'll exit.

Comment: If you use `n$ > 0` then for `$n == 1` you will return 1 step when it should be zero.